# Replace part column value with value from another column of same dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe with two columns:

```
Name          DATE
Name1         20200126
Name2         20200127
Name#DATE#    20200210
```

I need to replace all the #DATE# with the data from the DATE column, and get something like this:

```
Name          
Name1         
Name2         
Name20200210
```

How can I achieve this? I've tried things like this, without any good result..:

```
df_merged_tables["Name"].str.replace("#DATE#",merged_tables["DATE"])
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your solution is close

Maybe just needed to add an apply.

Try:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"Name":["Name1", "Name2", "Name#DATE#"], "Date":[20200126, 20200127, 20200210]})

df["NewColumn"] = df.apply(lambda row: row["Name"].replace("#DATE#", str(row["Date"])), axis = 1)
```

**Outputs:**

[image]

Comment: That worked.. thanks!!